# Changing/updating the attribute in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I was wondering if I could do this. Here's the following code:

```
<template>
    <modal :name="fruit" :opened="opened" :closed="onClose">

    ...code in here

    </modal>
</template>
```

I'm trying to change ':closed: onClose' to ":closed: onComplete"

Somewhere I have a function that completes the modal and I was wondering if this is valid once the method runs to have this inside of that one specific function:

```
 document.getElementByTagName("modal")[0].setAttribute('closed', 'onComplete');
```

:closed in binding to a function, so both onClose and onComplete represent functions. Is there an efficient way to dynamically update :close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a nice solution would be to add a flag variable like

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  data: {
    condition: false
  }
})
```

and then update it where it is needed like:

```
vm.condition = true;
```

and in UI use this logic:

```
<modal :name="fruit" :opened="opened" 
    v-bind="{ closed: condition ? onComplete : onClose }">
```